# How to customize the color of the JSON additionalRowClass in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm currently try to format the rows of a SharePoint Online list depending on a specific lookup Value. This works so far, but I need to know how I can use custom colors and not the predefined colours of Microsoft. E.g. #FF0000  instead of "sp-field-severity--warning" or how can I use my own class for the entire row and not just one field.

`{   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",   "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Status.lookupValue] == 'in progress', 'sp-field-severity--good', if([$Status.lookupValue] == 'on hold','sp-field-severity--warning', ''))" }`

Best regards

Matthias

I try to customized the JSON so far, but I don't know where I can add the custom color codes in HEX or RGB.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Per my test we are not able to add RGB code to format view. But you could use `ms-bgColor-[color]` instead of "sp-field-severity--warning" to change the color of a row.

For Reference: [MVP Article – Using Theme Colors in List Formatting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/mvp-article-using-theme-colors-in-list-formatting/)

My test result:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
   "additionalRowClass": "=if([$choice] == 'READY TO GO', 'ms-bgColor-sharedRed10', if([$choice] == 'NEW','ms-bgColor-sharedGreen10', ''))" 
}
```

[color.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y9Tn.jpg)

And here is a [blog](https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/) about different `ms-bgColor-[color]`.